# Is it possible to use C# with Salsa 20/12 so that Intel/AMD SSE2 acceleration is used?

Tags: c#, encryption, stream, cryptography, sse2

I'm interested in the eStream project and using C# to encrypt / decrypt data streams with Intel/AMD acceleration.

How can I use C# to interact with Intel/AMD hardware so I can get the following algorithms to work:

- Salsa 20/12
- Sosamaunk

Comment: Depends on what your C# compiles to. Using vanilla .NET and the CLR, it's extremely difficult to know / predict what instructions get JITed. You would need to resort to P/invoking a native library if you care what x86 instructions get used.

Comment: They'll work, but the JIT compiler never vectorizes any math (only copying and zeroing), so it'll just be scalar code.